# Why setState is not rebuilding my child widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

In this counter example, reproducible on dart pad, I am expecting the `child` widget to rebuild when I tap on the increment button **because** it is in the same tree as a the build tree of `CounterParentState`.

That or there is something about widget tree or the `setState` method that I don't understand.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class Controller {
  late CounterParentState view;

  void attach(CounterParentState v) {
    this.view = v;
  }

  int counter = 0;

  void incrementCounter() {
    counter++;
    this.view.applyState();
  }
}

class CounterChild extends StatelessWidget {
  final Controller controller;

  const CounterChild({Key? key, required this.controller}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'You have pushed the button this many times:',
          ),
          Text(
            '${controller.counter}',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final controller = Controller();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: CounterParent(
        title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page',
        controller: controller,
        child: CounterChild(controller: controller),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CounterParent extends StatefulWidget {
  final Controller controller;
  final String title;
  final Widget child;

  CounterParent({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.controller,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  CounterParentState createState() => CounterParentState();
}

class CounterParentState extends State<CounterParent> {
  void applyState() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    widget.controller.attach(this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: widget.child,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: widget.controller.incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Why I chose this design ?**

I choose this design because I wanted to be able to re-use the `CounterParent` and freely  replace the `child` of the `CounterParent`

```
class CounterStylishChild extends StatelessWidget {
  final Controller controller;

  const CounterStylishChild({Key? key, required this.controller}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'You have pushed the button this many times: (And I am stylish too)',
          ),
          Text(
            '${controller.counter}',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
class MyMoreStylishApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyMoreStylishApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MyMoreStylishAppState createState() => MyMoreStylishAppState();
}

class MyMoreStylishAppState extends State<MyMoreStylishApp> {

  final controller = Controller();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: CounterParent(
        title: 'Counter Parent with a better looking child',
        controller: controller,
        child: CounterStylishChild(controller: controller),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setState` is working as expected and rebuilding `CounterParent`, but you passed a `Widget` instance ("`child`") that is stored in `CounterParent` and stays constant as it's constructed in `MyAppState`, which is never rebuilt in your code. This is the equivalent of "storing" a widget, which some do to prevent unnecessary rebuilds.

For example, the [`AnimatedBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedBuilder-class.html) widget does this to prevent unnecessary rebuilds of larger children, while rebuilding the widgets that have changing values that create the animation.

The `AnimatedBuilder` example code may provide more understanding:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return AnimatedBuilder(
    animation: _controller,
    child: Container(
      width: 200.0,
      height: 200.0,
      color: Colors.green,
      child: const Center(
        child: Text('Whee!'),
      ),
    ),
    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
      return Transform.rotate(
        angle: _controller.value * 2.0 * math.pi,
        child: child,
      );
    },
  );
}
```

The "complex" child (the `Container`) is passed to the `AnimatedBuilder`, which stores the widget. It can then pass this widget as a parameter in the `builder` that is called rapidly. The `Transform` widget gets its new rotation value on every call of the `builder`, but the potentially "complex" child is never actually rebuilt.

This is identical to the situation you have here, except your situation is unintentional. It's inadvisable to have multiple widgets so dependent on each other and organized in such a complex manner like what you have here.

Though you don't ask for this in your question, I'll provide a fix. This may not be what you want and it may defeat the purpose of this elaborate design, but it's the simple way to make a pattern such as this function. Elaboration as to why you wanted to do this would be helpful if this solution is not satisfactory.

The `CounterChild` should be instantiated in the `CounterParent`. This way, when `setState` is called for the parent, a new instance of the child is create and it is rebuilt.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class Controller {
  late CounterParentState view;

  void attach(CounterParentState v) {
    this.view = v;
  }

  int counter = 0;

  void incrementCounter() {
    counter++;
    this.view.applyState();
  }
}

class CounterChild extends StatelessWidget {
  final Controller controller;

  const CounterChild({Key? key, required this.controller}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'You have pushed the button this many times:',
          ),
          Text(
            '${controller.counter}',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final controller = Controller();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: CounterParent(
        title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page',
        controller: controller,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CounterParent extends StatefulWidget {
  final Controller controller;
  final String title;

  CounterParent({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.controller,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  CounterParentState createState() => CounterParentState();
}

class CounterParentState extends State<CounterParent> {
  void applyState() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    widget.controller.attach(this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: CounterChild(controller: widget.controller),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: widget.controller.incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

If you'd like to keep the `CounterChild` where it is, you might consider using [`InheritedNotifier`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedNotifier-class.html):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class Controller extends ChangeNotifier {
  int counter = 0;

  void incrementCounter() {
    counter++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class Counter extends InheritedNotifier<Controller> { 
  const Counter({
    Key? key,
    required Controller controller,
    required Widget child,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child, notifier: controller);
  
  static Controller of(BuildContext context) {
    final Controller? result = context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<Counter>()?.notifier;
    assert(result != null, 'No Controller found in context');
    return result!;
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(Counter old) => notifier?.counter != old.notifier?.counter;
}

class CounterChild extends StatelessWidget {
  const CounterChild({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'You have pushed the button this many times:',
          ),
          Text(
            '${Counter.of(context).counter}',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final Controller controller = Controller();
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Counter(
        controller: controller,
        child: CounterParent(
          title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page',
          child: CounterChild(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CounterParent extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final Widget child;

  CounterParent({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  CounterParentState createState() => CounterParentState();
}

class CounterParentState extends State<CounterParent> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: widget.child,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: Counter.of(context).incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Or if you want to preserve more of your original structure, you need to pass your `MyApp` `setState` instead of your `CounterParent` `setState` so both the parent and child are rebuilt:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class Controller extends ChangeNotifier {
  int counter = 0;

  void incrementCounter() {
    counter++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class CounterChild extends StatelessWidget {
  final Controller controller;
  
  const CounterChild({Key? key, required this.controller}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'You have pushed the button this many times:',
          ),
          Text(
            '${controller.counter}',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late final Controller controller;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    
    controller = Controller()
      ..addListener(()=>setState((){}));
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: CounterParent(
        controller: controller,
        title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page',
        child: CounterChild(controller: controller),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CounterParent extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final Widget child;
  final Controller controller;

  CounterParent({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.controller,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  CounterParentState createState() => CounterParentState();
}

class CounterParentState extends State<CounterParent> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: widget.child,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: widget.controller.incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this great answer! I really appreciate the example of the AnimationBuilder and you even bothered suggesting a fix to my code. I also updated to question to explain why I choose this design but your answer is enough to deserve to be accepted.  I would still appreciate if you could review my design choice and suggest a fix

Comment: @TSR Made an edit. Not a perfect solution, but I believe it keeps more of your original intent.